# Include Node.JS + Socket.IO in Symfony2 application

Tags: node.js, symfony, websocket, socket.io

I have done many researches and it seems I can't find the proper solution. I am confident in PHP. I also have done some tutorials on `Node.JS` and `Socket.IO` and I'm currently learning `Symfony2` but I can't see how I can merge the two to achieve my goal.

My goal is to set up real-time notification for back-end users of my app. This app is a e-commerce website and I want the admin behind the scenes to be warned as soon as an order is made by a visual notification in the upper right corner of the admin panel. My server use `FreeBSD`.

My plan is to use `Node.JS` and `Socket.IO` to achieve this. If there is a better plan, I'm willing to hear about it. Otherwise, I cannot find proper resources to tell me how I can include `Node.JS` and `Socket.IO` to a `Symfony2` app. I use composer to install bundles but I haven't used NPM with Symfony2.

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547607/apache-symfony2-https-node-js-socket-io-socket-emit-not-firing), [this link](http://devblog.lexik.fr/symfony2/notifications-via-websocket-avec-symfony2-et-node-js-2679) and [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555551/integrate-node-js-with-symfony2-or-php) to help me out but none of these tell me how I can install `Node.JS` in a `Symfony2` app.

If someone could help me with the steps to complete to make me start developping this feature, I'd be glad.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you think of / find any ways that this might be achieved entirely or mostly in Symfony? Would that be a silly idea? Should I just bite the bullet and install node?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'd essentially like to make an instant messaging system across lots of devices simultaneously, so need to send and receive over sockets, but would like to use symfony2 authentication. Do you have any thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For those who might be interested in the answer:

`$ su -`

**Install Node.JS**

`$ cd /usr/ports/www/node`

`$ make install clean`

**Install NPM**

`$ cd /usr/ports/www/npm`

`$ make install clean`

**Install Socket.IO**

`$ cd /path/to/your/project/js/public/files`

`$ npm install socket.io`

**Develop the code**

*app.js*

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('./index.html', 'utf-8', function(error, content) {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        res.end(content);
    });
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('newOrder', function () {
        socket.broadcast.emit('message', 'Nouvelle commande');
    });
});

server.listen(4321);
```

*Front-end*

```
<script src="{{ asset('http://localhost:4321/socket.io/socket.io.js') }}"></script>

<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4321');

        $('form').on('submit', function() {
            socket.emit('newOrder', '1');
        });

    });
</script>
```

*Back-End*

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {    
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4321');

        socket.on('message', function(message) {
            alert(message);
        });
    });

</script>
```

**Launch server**

`$ node app.js`

That's all!

Comment: Just wondering, where in the back-end should that script live, regarding to symfony?